# 数字から始まる変数でエラーになる

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

https://coinmarketcap.com/ja/api/　から値を取ってきたいのですが出来ません。
下のソースで　24h_volume_usd　が数字から始まることで不都合が起きているのですが・・どこを修正すれば良いでしょうか？

```
function getCoin24h_volume_usd(currency) {
  //coinmarketcap API call 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + currency + "/");
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
  var 24h_volume_usd = results[0].24h_volume_usd;
  return 24h_volume_usd;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

JavaScriptを含め、多くのプログラミング言語では**変数名の一文字目**に数字を使用することはできません(二文字目以降に含めるのは可)。

JavaScriptの場合は

> 一文字目：半角の英字、アンダースコア、ドル記号
>   二文字目以降：半角の英数字、アンダースコア、ドル記号

Comment: 1文字目は半角の英字だけでなく、Unicode の Lu Ll Lt Lm Lo Nl カテゴリーの文字が使えます。漢字やかなも大丈夫です。2文字目以降も数字だけでなくいろいろな文字が追加されます。